# Cakephp Behavior wrong model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am writing a Behavior

```
<?php

class LogsBehavior extends ModelBehavior {


        public $Model;

        public function setup(Model $model, $config = array()) {
            $this->Model = $model;
        }

        public function afterSave(Model $Model, $created, array $options = array()) {

            pr($this->Model);
            exit;


        }

}
```

Ok, so when I check the setup method i have in $model:

```
Comprovante Object
(...)
```

When i save the entry and i reach afterSave method the $Model property is

```
Comprovante Object
    (...)
```

BUT my $this->Model is:

```
Cliente Object
```

It seems the previous object is there not the Comprovante...

Someone can help me?

Comprovante.php

```
public $actsAs = array('Logs');
```

Comment: That is not how you can or should program behaviors in 2.x. Models share behaviors, thus your approach is doomed to fail.

Answer (score 1):

You may not use a shared attribute here, for the outlined reason above.

Always provide methods, that get passed to the Model as first param:

```
public function someMethod(Model $Model, ...) {
    $this->_someMethod($Model, ...);
}

protected function _someMethod(Model $Model, ...) {}
```

etc

See how current core and (popular!) plugin/userland behaviors do it and embrace their way of doing things.

Comment: Ok, i understood.. And in the _someMethod can I set properties for a single Model?

Comment: No properties are set via $settings. As I already told you take a look at the source code, it tells you everything: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php#L68